# Extruding along an edge without creating new faces

Tags: vertices

So I am working on a fun little project. It's been months since I last created something in blender and even that was my first time. First up: [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1Kozr06Abr_NGNrOTVaUHBDQ2c) is the file.

[image]

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to make all the edges "extrude" (maybe it's the wrong word) so that this shuriken gets blades.

I've been googling for hours, but I cannot seem to describe what I want in a simple search query. I hope someone knows what I mean, any help is greatly appreciated!

P.S. After making the blades I would like them to kind of "inverse bevel". I couldn't find any info on that either, so if anyone could point me into a direction I'd be quite happy.

Comment: Could you provide some images with desired effects?

Comment: Maybe you are searching for scaling along normals (Alt+S).

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was looking for! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Select the edge  in edit mode and then grab it with <kbd>G</kbd> and moving it along any axis by pressing the respective keys <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd> and <kbd>Z</kbd> or you can do it by hand. This way no extra faces will be created. Hope it will work

Answer (score 1):

It was scaling along normals als Mr Zak pointed out