# How can i extrude a text or element to the sides correctly?

Tags: modeling, extrude

I want to make a border for a text, with extrude option (no other option than that) because i will apply that too to another models that are plain like text later.

When i extrude the object, like on this example, i want to scale it but it moves to a single side, but i need it to be like a perfect border. of every element of the model, when i extrude them together.

And even, if possible extrude at the same time the inside part of the 'e'.

*Edit: it's like using the Mesh Option 'Extrude individual' but not by separating the faces as different cubes, just like a general extrude, for creating a 'border'.*

[image]

Thanks in regards.

Comment: This would be relatively easy if you hadn't converted text to a mesh

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, to do what i wanted is to Scale Normals ( ALT + S)

[Extruding along an edge without creating new faces](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79126/extruding-along-an-edge-without-creating-new-faces)